# How do I group rows by month in a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boxplot

I need to create a box plot of some timed data, with a box representing the raw data for each month. Something like this:

[image]

Now let's try to create that using pandas:

```
matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

N_DAYS = 100
dates = pd.date_range('20130101', periods=N_DAYS)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(N_DAYS,1), index=dates)
```

I can resample by month (code `M`) and apply aggregate functions such as `median`:

```
df.resample('M').median()
```

However, I can't create a box plot of the data:

```
df.resample('M').boxplot();
```

This creates one box representing the distribution of the mean for each month.

[image]

Also, I get the following warning:

```
FutureWarning: 
.resample() is now a deferred operation
You called boxplot(...) on this deferred object which materialized it into a dataframe
by implicitly taking the mean.  Use .resample(...).mean() instead
```

How do I create a boxplot of the raw data for each month?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you need create new column for `period` first for stratified boxplot using the `by` keyword argument to create groupings:

```
df['per'] = df.index.to_period('M')
df.boxplot(by='per')
```

[image: graph]

You can also check [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#box-plots).